# iReport pattern formatting not working

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I am generating a report using JasperReports and using iReport to design it. Running Jaspersoft 4 and using iReport 4.1.3 to design the report. The report generates fine as a preview in iReport using dates, percentages and floats being rounded off. However, when it is generated via HTML the formatting fails completely.

- I have assured that it is the same report by changing column titles to view live changes.
- I have checked the XML to check for missing format attributes and they all exist appropriately.

Is this an issue with the software (Jaspersoft/iReport) or am I missing something?

*I can provide examples and any other information if needed.*

Comment: Can you post the snippet? Did you generate HTML with help of JR API?

Comment: It's works fine for me (iReport v 4.1.3).

Answer (score 1):

In version 3.7 I had a number of bad formatting issues if the data types did not match up completely.

i.e. if the field was defined as a java.lang.integer the text box also had to be defined as a java.lang.integer or the pattern was ignored.

Also found that using the iReport that matches your version of Jasper is a requirement to avoid some of the funkiness that you are seeing.

Comment: +1 because of pointing iReport version relationship with jasper version.